# Is the plethysm of two polynomials the same as the substitution of one into another?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Plethysm is defined in Ian MacDonald's book "Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials" (1979, 1995).

Let $f, g$ be polynomials, and write $g$ as a sum of monomials:

$$ g = \sum_\alpha u_\alpha x^\alpha . $$

Now introduce the set of fictitious variables $y_i$ defined by:

$$ \prod (1+ y_i t) = \prod_\alpha (1 + x^\alpha t)^{u_\alpha} $$

and define

$$ f \circ g = f(y_1, y_2, ...) . $$

Another way of calling a plethysm is "composition".

Is this the same as substituting $g$ into $f$?

Comment: What do you mean by substituting a symmetric function into another?

Comment: It may sound silly, I mean substituting g into f, as in the composition of 2 functions.  I can't figure out what that product formula is saying...